# Functional component returns object Object in react

Tags: reactjs, list, react-functional-component

I want to output the values of a json object. On each fetch, the type of values change from string to null. That's why I have the for loop and the if statement. Each constant inside the loop outputs the correct value but after it is added to listItems each `<li>` just returns [object Object].
I tried using `<li>${value} (${time})</li>` but this outputs the tags `<li>` as a string value.

```
function ValuesList(props) {
  
    let listItems = '';
    for(let i=1; i<=15; i+=1){
        const value = props.myDrink[`strValue` + i]; *//json code is: strValue1, strValue2, ... strValue15, with some of null value.*
        const time = props.myDrink[`strTime` + i];
        if (typeof value === 'string'){
            listItems += <li>{value} ({time})</li>
        }
    }
   
    return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>)
};
```

I have done this in jQuery before but I need to make it work in react. Should I change the `+=`? If not, what line should I fix? This is part of my first react project. Please help, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than concatenating JSX values into an empty string, push them into an array (with a key attribute):

```js
let listItems = [];
 for(let i=1; i<=15; i+=1){
        const value = props.myDrink[`strValue` + i]; 
        const time = props.myDrink[`strTime` + i];
        if (typeof value === 'string'){
            listItems.push(<li key={/* some unique key. Probably your value */}>{value} ({time})</li>);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should directly map your items.  There is no need to do what you used to do in jQuery.

if your drinks prop is an array

```
return (
 <ul>
  {props.drinks(map(({value, time}, i)=>{
    if (typeof value === 'string'){
     return <li key={`item-${i}`}>{value} ({time})</li>
    }
  })
 </ul>
)
```

if your drinks props is an object

```
return (
 <ul>
  {Object.entires(props.drinks).map(({ value, time }, i) => {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
     return <li key={`item-${i}`}>{value} ({time})</li>;
    }
   })}
 </ul>
)
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading the question wrong, this won't work because props.myDrink is structured in a very hacky way. If that input value is cleaned up, this is 100% the way to go.

Comment: It looks like the OP has an array of 15 items that they are looping then referencing the array based on the index.  This is an educated guess based on the limited provided info.

Comment: Look at where value and time are coming from, though. They're all properties of the same item. The first value is myDrink[strValue1], etc.

Comment: If it's an object the op can map the object with Object.entries(props.drinks).map(...).

Comment: Wouldn't that break up the value and time properties?

Comment: Possibly - they could just access it how they are currently.   The OP didn't provide enough info to get an exact answer.  There is enough info in the answer to answer their original question.

Comment: I would still need the `i` loop to reference the json code. And yes, this json is a little complicated to map through. The `.push()` worked. Thank you!